# Finding average values for duplicate rows without having duplicate id in python

Tags: pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = {'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'age':[20,20,20,30,30,40], 
  'sex':['male', 'male','male', 'female','female','male'],
  'height':[160,160,160,140,140,150], 
  '360':[2982.921493,3354.249711,6537.645604,4812.173331,5215.383633,9030.854630],
  '362':[2987.832519,3363.234132,6536.772994,4808.975554,5211.137003,9022.354770],
  '364':[2983.867920,3375.331914,6526.037739,4805.191329,5197.668410,9026.522422],
  '366':[2983.712225,3379.594261,6522.214792,4807.009706,5192.256358,9028.738379],
  '368':[2999.205088,3383.982632,6534.044523,4806.750073,5201.491676,9026.864575]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

This has duplicate readings (1,2,3 is same, 4,5 is same) but `id` column is unique.

**PART 1**

I want to generate a new column, where duplicated rows have same identifier. I can use `age`, `sex` and `height` to find duplicated rows.

Output dataframe:

[image]

**PART 2**

I also want to take average of the numeric columns and consolidate them as one row,
so consolidated dataframe would look like

Output :

```
new_id  age   sex   height    360                362               364             366           368
  1a     20   male   160      avg of 3 rows    avg of 3 rows   avg of 3 rows   avg of 3 rows   avg of 3 rows
  2b     30  female  140      avg of 2 rows    avg of 2 rows   avg of 2 rows   avg of 2 rows   avg of 2 rows
  3c     40   male   150      as is             as is           as is            as is           as is
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `duplicated` to identify the duplicated rows and `cumsum` for the blocks:

```
indicators = ['age','sex','height']

groups = (~df.duplicated(subset=indicators)).cumsum()
agg_dict = {k: 'first' if k in indicators else 'mean' for k in df.columns[1:]}
df.groupby(groups).agg(agg_dict)
```

Output:

```
   age     sex  height          360          362          364          366  \
1   20    male     160  4291.605603  4295.946548  4295.079191  4295.173759   
2   30  female     140  5013.778482  5010.056279  5001.429869  4999.633032   
3   40    male     150  9030.854630  9022.354770  9026.522422  9028.738379   

           368  
1  4305.744081  
2  5004.120875  
3  9026.864575
```

Comment: Is it possible to get average in the numeric columns? The output dataframe has sum of all duplicates. I was looking to get average of the duplicate values.

Comment: Sure replace `'sum'` with `'mean'` in `agg_dict`. See updated answer.